# What's a good jQuery ligthbox plugin that cycles through images? (like a carousel)

Tags: jquery, image, slider, lightbox

I'm looking for a jQuery lightbox plugin that has the ability to, with it's next and previous buttons, cycle through images repeatedly. Like a carousel effect.

I've been using `jQuery Lightbox Plugin (balupton edition)` but that doesn't have the option to continue cycling through images. It reaches the last image in the array and then disables the 'next' button.

So to save me some time coding, what are some plugins you can recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, I like jQuery Tools Scrollable:

- http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/
- http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html

And jQuery Cycle looks nice too:

- http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

http://fancybox.net/ has a gallery option that is nice.